# Witness for $2-$dimensional irreducible representation of $Q_8$ over an algebraically closed field

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Show that the $2-$dimensional irreducible representation of $Q_8$ can be realized in the space $V$ of functions $f : Q_8 → F$ such that $f(gi)= \sqrt{−1}f(g)$ (the action of $G$ is by right multiplication, $g ◦ f(x)= f(xg)$).

So far,I only proved that $V$ is a $G-space$. I am trying to find a basis for $V$, but I don't know how to find it. I tried to construct one, but the process is complicated, and after I construct a function, proving the function belongs to $V$ is again complicated. Is there any easier approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Being two-dimensional seems to suggest that you need two values. So just fix $f(i)=\lambda$ and $f(j)=\mu$. Then you have to prove that you can extend this to a unique function by the rule $f(gi)=\sqrt{-1}f(g)$. To finish you just have to prove that for each of these functions $f$ and $gf$ are linearly independent.