# Is there an error in this problem about the two-dimensional representation of the quaternion group?

Tags: representation-theory

This is from the text *Introduction to Representation Theory* by Etingof *et al.* In the PDF lecture notes, this exercise is unnumbered but is located in section 3.3 on examples of representations of finite groups.

> **Exercise 4.3.1.** Show that the 2-dimensional irreducible representation of $Q_8$ can be realized in the space of functions $f : Q_8 \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(gi) = \sqrt{-1}f(g)$ (the action of $G$ is by right multiplication, $g \circ f(x) = f(xg)$).

I can't seem to make sense of this problem. It seems to be saying that the space $V$ of functions so defined forms a representation of $Q_8$. I am assuming that by "$G$" Etingof means $Q_8$. But the action defined in the problem is not a valid representation---it doesn't seem to map an element of $V$ to an element of $V$.

Suppose $f(1) = 1, f(i) = i, f(-1) = -1, f(-i) = -i, f(\pm j) = f(\pm k) = 0$. Then $f(xi) = if(x)$ for all $x \in Q_8$. Now consider the function $j \circ f$, which according to the problem is defined so that $(j \circ f)(x) = f(xj)$. Then

- $(j \circ f)(j) = f(jj) = f(-1) = -1$
- $(j \circ f)(ji) = f(jij) = f(i) = i$

therefore $(j \circ f)(ji) \ne i (j \circ f)(j)$ and it would appear that $j \circ f \notin V$.

On the other hand, if the condition for $V$ is that $f(ix) = \sqrt{-1} f(x)$ (the $i$ multiplies on the left, not the right) then I think the problem makes sense.

Is this an error or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1780355/witness-for-2-dimensional-irreducible-representation-of-q-8-over-an-algebrai?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another user posted an answer agreeing that it should be $f(ix) = \sqrt{-1}(x)$, but deleted it for some reason.

Anyway, I emailed Etingof. He agreed that the book contains a misprint and that $f(xi)$ should be $f(ix)$.